# Comment with replies in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I am working on blog application in django and I added comment section section in blog but I am having problem show replies for parent comment.

**Models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField(("comment_text"))
    user = models.ForeignKey("account.User", related_name=("comment_user"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", related_name=("comment_post"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name=("replies"), on_delete = models.CASCADE , blank= True ,null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(("Comment Timestamp"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**blog.html**

```
<div Class ="container">
    <h3><b>Comments...</b></h3> 
  <div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-8">
      <div class ="row">
        {% if not post.comment_post.all %}
          No comments Yet
        {% else %}
        {% for comment in post.comment_post.all %}
        {% if comment.reply is Null%}
        <br>
        <hr>
        <div class = "col-2">
          <img class="rounded-circle" width="80" height="60" src="{{comment.user.profile_image.url}}">
        </div>
        <div class ="col-10">
          <strong>{{comment.user.first_name}} {{comment.user.last_name}}</strong> 
          <span class ="float-end"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> {{comment.timestamp.date}}</span>
          <p>{{comment.comment_text}}</p>
        </div>
        {%endif%}
        {% endfor%}
        <hr>
        <br>
        {% endif %}
        <div>
          {{form|crispy}}
          <span class ="float-start">Post Comment as: <b>{{request.user.first_name}} {{request.user.last_name}} </b></span>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-end mb-2">Post comment</button>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="col-4 bg-info">
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin,DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'MainSite/blogpost.html'
```

I cant think of anyway to show replies under parent comment.

Thanks in advance and any advice will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

you can create a new model for comment answers and inherit comment model with foreign key

example:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    #your fields (example; author and body)

class CommentAnswer(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other fields (example; author or body)
```

and on template, you can use 'for loop' for showing all answer:

```html
<h2> {{comment.author}} </h2>
    <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
        {% for answer in comment.commentanswer_set.all %}
            <p>{{answer.author}} -- {{answer.body}} </p>
        {% endif %}
```

and also in your 'DetailView': `model = Comment` which of mother class (for this example)